# How to convert '\N' character to empty string using Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a table with field 'str'. 
When I run

```
select str from mytable where str is null
```

it prints null. But when I run:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY "/path/to/dir" 
select str from mytable where str is null;
```

There is '**\N**' characters in

> "/path/to/dir"

I want know if there is a way to change '\N' character to empty string while I write result to local file.

Answer (score 2):

**Demo for @AshishSingh answer**

**hive**

```
create table mytable (i int,j int,k int);
insert into mytable values (1,2,null),(null,5,null),(7,null,9);

select * from mytable
;
```

---

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| mytable.i | mytable.j | mytable.k |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | 2         | NULL      |
| NULL      | 5         | NULL      |
| 7         | NULL      | 9         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

---

```
insert overwrite local directory "/tmp/mytable" 
row format delimited fields terminated by "," null defined as '' 
select * from mytable
;
```

---

**bash**

```
cat /tmp/mytable/*
1,2,
,5,
7,,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:-

```
  INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY "/path/to/dir" 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t" NULL DEFINED AS '' 
select str from mytable where str is null;
```

You may remove `FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"` if not required

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always use CASE-WHEN statement something like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN str is null then '' ELSE str END;
```

Remember that you can change the way you treat null fields using this table property:

> "serialization.null.format"

Answer (score 0):

Yes need small change. You query returns always `null` results so directly put `" " (empty string)` to file.

```
select if(str is null, " ", str) str from mytable where str is null
```

Comment: how about other column that also could be null, write as ''

Comment: @user4234323 check answer, i modified.